# Holomorphic function $F:\Bbb H\to \Bbb C$ having the bounded sequence $\{ir_n\}$ as zeros.

Tags: complex-analysis

Stein and Shakarchi, *Complex Analysis*, Chapter 8 Problem 5.

> 1. Suppose that $F:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and bounded. Also, suppose
>      $F(z)$ vanishes when $z=ir_n$, $n=1,2,3,\ldots,$ where $\{r_n\}$ is
>      a bounded sequence of positive numbers. Prove that if $\sum r_n=\infty$ then $F=0$.
> 2. If $\sum r_n<\infty$, it is possible to construct a bounded function
>      on the upper half-plane with zeros precisely at the points $ir_n$.

There is something weird about the first part. If the sequence $\{ir_n\}$ is infinite then it has a convergent subsequence since it's bounded. Hence the zeros of $F$ accumulate in $\Bbb H$ and $F$ is zero. Am I missing something here?

Comment: For other readers: [This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4167586/917479) is about the same exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{ir_n\}$ accumulates at a point other than $0$, then $F=0$ is trivial as you said. But the problem is requiring you to show that if $\{ir_n\}$ accumulates at $0$ and the convergence $r_n\to 0$ is "slow" enough to make $\sum_n r_n =\infty$, then $F$ must be $0$. Put differently, if $F\neq 0$ is bounded on the upper half plane and $\{z_n\}$ are zeros of $F$, then it must be that $\Im(z_n)\to 0 $ fast enough to make $$
\sum_n \Im (z_n)<\infty.$$

Comment: what do you suggest in this case? Does the Jensen formula help? Should we work with the unit disk instead of the upper half plane?

Comment: That's the trick of this problem. How can we transform the domain into the unit disk without losing analyticity of $F$? (Hint)Maybe you can use $z = \frac{aw+b}{cw+d}$ or something like this.

Comment: Use the map $T:\Bbb D\to \Bbb H$ defined by $z\mapsto i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$?

Comment: I guess that will work :)

Comment: what about the second part?

Comment: Blaschke factor will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $(ir_n)$ accumulates at a point of $\mathbb{C}$, but not necessarily at a point of $\mathbb{H}$.  Indeed, if $r_n\to 0$ then they accumulate only at $0$, which is not in $\mathbb{H}$.